# Add a column to all MySQL Select Queries in a single shot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, dialect

Trying to add a comment to all MySQL Select Queries in my web application at runtime.

For example, the original queries in the code looks like:

```
select a,b,c from ......
select x,y from...
```

All of these need to be modified ***at runtime*** to:

```
select a,b,c /*Comment*/ from ...
select x,y /*Comment*/ from ...
```

The application runs on Hibernate 4.2.1.
Only solution I can think of is extending the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` and add the `/*Comment*/` in the new `CustomMySQLDialect`.

A little confused on which method to modify to accomplish this. Would appreciate any pointer in the right direction.

Can `transformSelectString(java.lang.String)` method in `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` be overridden to accomplish this?

EDIT 1:
transformSelectString in a Custom MySQL Dialect is not working for runtime SQL modification

Comment: if you are using hibernate, how will adding a column (which presumably hibernate does not understand) help you?

Comment: How exactly do you call this "TESTVALUE"? Where does it come from? I didn't get it yet..

Comment: I cannot modify the original queries but I need to add an extra string constant in the query before its execution. "TESTVALUE" is just a string constant Leo

Comment: i don't need hibernate to understand or map the column. Just need to pass a value to the query before execution.

Comment: Why do you want to this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to insert a comment/value for audit logging purpose. Need to store some extra data in every query being executed without affecting the output of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Custom DB Interceptor

```
package com.felix.dao.interceptor;
import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor;

public class CustomDBInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

  @Override
  public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    String commentStr = "/*Comment*/"
    return super.onPrepareStatement(commentStr+sql);
  }

}
```

In the Spring Context file, configure the Interceptor for the session factory:

```
<bean id="customDBInterceptor" class="com.felix.dao.interceptor.CustomDBInterceptor"/>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <ref bean="customDBInterceptor"/>
    </property>
    ...
</bean>
```

Make sure the Custom DB Interceptor does not have a cyclic dependency on the sessionFactory.
With the above, all queries fired through the session factory, are intercepted, modified and then passed to the `onPrepareStatement` method.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to add an extra column with a constant value, try giving it an alias:

```
SELECT a, b, c, "TESTVALUE" AS `new_column` FROM ...
```

Comment: My aim is to add a constant to all the select queries being executed in the application.