# Hidden column setter/getter with Hibernate/JPA/Spring-Data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a multi-tenant architecture, where each table has a `namespace` field. Whenever any method is executing, the `ThreadLocal` storage has access to the current `namespace`. What I do want is my business layer to be completely agnostic of the concept of a namespace. To give an example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class Users {
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    ...
}
```

The table `users` is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    first_name CHARACTER VARYING,
    last_name CHARACTER VARYING,
    namespace CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL
    ...
);
```

I am skipping the primary key and other fields for brevity. Any query of the type `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (condition)` needs to essentially be `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (condition & namespace = :1)`, or in terms of `spring-data`, `findUsersByName(String name)` should be `findUsersByNameAndNamespace(String name, String namespace)`. Also, every `save` operation should require the model to be populated with the namespace.

However, I do not want to include the namespace in the model definition. This is a two-sided problem:

1. Every `fetch` needs to have the namespace set in the query.
2. Every `save` needs to save the namespace in the model.

While, I have absolutely no clue how to solve the first problem, the second problem can be (partially) solved by using a parent class `TenantedModel` which has a `namespace` property which is then set using a Hibernate interceptor. The problem with that is the business layer is still able to see the `namespace` attribute.

Is there a clean way to do this using JPA with Spring Data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interceptors to modify SQL generated by hibernate.

```
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    String newSQLWithNamespace = sql+" and (namespace = "+ nameSpaceValue+")";
    return super.onPrepareStatement(newSQLWithNamespace);
}
```

See e.g. [Add a column to all MySQL Select Queries in a single shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718200/add-a-column-to-all-mysql-select-queries-in-a-single-shot)

You interceptor can read the thread local namespace value and change the SQL.