# How to set annotation's values according to properties?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate's ORM and hibernate-generator to generate the `Entity` in the annotation way. I need to switch database frequently (dev/release). So, I have to change the entity's annotation every time. I want to know if there is a way to configure it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my", catalog = "dev_db")
public class MyEntity {

}
```

As you can see, I've to change the catalog every time. How to configure it according to a `jdbc.properties`?

Comment: is it possible to introduce a dedicated catalog parameter for your case? then you can put the datalog in a config bean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interceptors to modify SQL generated by hibernate.

```
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    String superSQL = super.onPrepareStatement(newSQLWithNamespace);
    //replace all catalog occurencies with desired value in the superSQL
    return superSQL;
}
```

See e.g. [Add a column to all MySQL Select Queries in a single shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718200/add-a-column-to-all-mysql-select-queries-in-a-single-shot)

Your interceptor can read the catalog value from config and change the SQL.